# Dual Settlement Market Backtesting and Analysis

Tags: backtesting, python, commodities

An interesting problems I have been dealing with as a relatively new quant to the Electricity markets is the difficulty of back testing.

The issues I have been having with backtesting are that the framework needs to be able to work over two series, a purchase in the day ahead market and a sale in the real time market 24hr after. some of the backtesting frameworks like [bt](http://pmorissette.github.io/bt/index.html#features) and [backtrader](https://www.backtrader.com/) work great for normal single series models but don't hold up for a double series market, atleast with out significant customization which may be the fastest route.

Wondering if anyone has encountered a similar problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`backtrader` supports the spot/day-ahead pattern, which was developed explicity for energy markets. See

- https://www.backtrader.com/blog/posts/2017-03-15-future-vs-spot/future-vs-spot.html
- https://community.backtrader.com/topic/221/power-futures-settlement